# Как сделать бесконечое итерирование? Python 3

Tags: python, итераторы, next

Всем привет! Только что зарегалась, пишу впервые. Большие трудности в понимании `__iter__`, `__next__`.
Ниже в коде я пытаюсь упомянутые методы переписать так, чтобы в цикле `for` для моего словаря после последнего элемента был снова первый. Подскажите плиз, что не так?

```py
class Users:

    with open('users.json', 'r') as json_data:
        users = json.load(json_data)
        new_users = []
        for i in users:
            new_users.append(
                {'name': i['name'], 'gender': i['gender'], 'address': i['address'], 'age': i['age'], 'books': []})

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index == len(self.new_users):
            self.index = 0
            return self.new_users[self.index]
```

Comment: self.index нигде не увеличивается. да и return не на том уровне - но это можно списать на потерю форматирования при оформлении вопроса

Answer (score 2):

1. Возможно, вы привели не весь код класса, но у вас нигде не устанавливается начальное значение `self.index`, обычно это делается в методе `__init__()`
2. `self.index` никогда не достигнет `len(self.new_users)`, т.к. нигде нет увеличения `self.index`
3. `return` не на том уровне.

```py
class Users:
    new_users = ["Alice", "Bob", "Cindy"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.index = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index >= len(self.new_users):
            self.index = 0
  
        result = self.new_users[self.index]
        self.index += 1
        return result
```